# Calculating matrix with given polynomial linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

> Calculate the matrix M(T) representing the given linear
> transformations (relative to the standard basis)
>
> $(A) T:P3(R)→P3(R)$ defined by
>
> $T(p(x))=2x^2p(0)+p(1)−(x+2x^2)p(2)$
>
> $M(T)=...$
>
> (B)  $T:P3(R)→P3(R)$ defined by
>
> $T(p(x))=(x−2)p′′(x)−(2p(x)+(2+x)p′(x))$
>
> $M(T)=...$

So, I have this question to solve. I was studying how to calculate matrices, but I'm kinda stuck at polynomials having no idea how to do them. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hey, if you are okay with the solution, you may accept the answer. Thanks! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3286/516174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

First think about the basis elements of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. Since  $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space of polynomials of degree atmost three. Let $B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ be a basis *(Verify This)* of  $P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

$A$. When $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that   $T(p(x))=2x^2p(0)+p(1)−(x+2x^2)p(2)$.
Now, $$T(1)=(1)\cdot1+(-1)\cdot x+(0)\cdot x^2+(0)\cdot x^3$$
$$T(x)=(1)\cdot1+(-2)\cdot x+(-4)\cdot x^2+(0)\cdot x^3$$
$$T(x^2)=(1)\cdot1+(-4)\cdot x+(-8)\cdot x^2+(0)\cdot x^3$$
$$T(x^3)=(1)\cdot1+(-8)\cdot x+(-16)\cdot x^2+(0)\cdot x^3$$

Now, the matrix representation of $T$ is:

$$M(T)=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&1\\-1&-2&-4&-8\\0&-4&-8&-16\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$B$. Similarly try this, first define the linear transformation on the basis elements and then form a matrix.

Comment: Can you please, show the matrix of B, I'm kinda bad at derivatives so, the main problem I'm stuck is B.

Comment: You have to deal with $1,x,x^2,x^3$ only. You will find their derivatives easily, I believe. For part (B), define $T(p(x))=(x−2)p′′(x)−(2p(x)+(2+x)p′(x))$ on $B$ as done in the answer, then you have to write those values of $T(p(x))$ in the linear combination of  $1,x,x^2,x^3$ as shown above. The matrix for the linear transformation defined in part (B) with respect to basis $B$ is:$$M(T)=\begin{bmatrix} -2&-2&-4&0\\0&-3&-2&-12\\0&0&-4&0\\ 0&0&0&-5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @user9414, BTW you should learn differentiation first before reading linear algebra. If you are not good with derivatives, you won't be able to understand that the derivatives can be seen as linear transformations. This is the beauty of mathematics. Everything is connected to each other.