# Find the matrix representation $T_{B}^{B}$ of this $T \in (\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Context: Linear Algebra Course.
Please , dont edit a,b,c are right.
Given $T \in (\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) $ such that $$T(a,b,c)=(-8x+9y-27z,3x-2y+9z, 3x-3y+10z)$$
Find the matrix of representation. 
It looks like a simple question. But I havent done it before. This question is related to matrix diagonalization.
Can you provide me some hints to find it?. Thanks in advance.

Here is the RIGHT ANSWER  by JCH:

$ A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(K), \ \ 1\leq i \leq j \leq n, $

$ T(\alpha_{j}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}\beta_{i}$

$ T(\alpha_{1}) = T(1,0, 0) = (-8, 3, 3)$

$ T(\alpha_{2}) = T(0,1, 0) = (9, 2, -3)$

$ T(\alpha_{3}) = T(0,0, 1) = (-27, 9, 10)$

$ A(T)_{st}^{st} = \left[ \begin{matrix} -8 & 9 & -27\\ 3 & -2 & 9 \\ 3 & -3 & 10 \end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: As I told you before: If $x = y = z = 0$, your $T$ is the zero mapping and therefore, the matrix is $A = 0$. In any other case, $T$ is not linear.

Comment: So you mean -8x+9y-27z=0  ,3x-2y+9z=0 , 3x-3y+10z=0.

Comment: Yes, and this fulfilled iff $x = y = z = 0$.

Comment: @Malu, Can you prove that $T$ is linear?

Comment: I have several items. 1) matrix representation. 2) $det(A-\lambda I_{3})$ 3)Eigenvalues and 4) eigenvectors. That's why It's important to find the matrix in the right way.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $T(x,y,z)$ instead of $T(a,b,c)$

Comment: Dont edit a,b and c. Trey re right. It is the statement.

Comment: @Malu What exactly is your question now? I told you several times that what you have written makes no sense (you still did not define $x, y$ and $z$). If you don't clarify this, this post has good chances to getting closed.

Comment: @Malu, you should take a look at this answer.https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3643691/516174

Comment: @Learning JCH  DID IT. IT'S THE RIGHT ANSWER. TAKE A  LOOK  AT THE ANSWER BELOW.               
  Closed. This question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.
 

Closed yesterday by Jan, Avi Steiner, Jean-Claude Arbaut, URL, Feng Shao.(Private feedback for you)

Comment: The answer given by JCH is correct if you write $T(x, y, z)$ at the beginning. If you still insist on $T(a, b, c)$, the answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: Because you dont understand , it doesnt mean my post need more context. Matrix representation of a linear transformation is a topic of Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(K), \ \ 1\leq i \leq j \leq n, $

$ T(\alpha_{j}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}\beta_{i}$

$ T(\alpha_{1}) = T(1,0, 0) = (-8, 3, 3)$

$ T(\alpha_{2}) = T(0,1, 0) = (9, 2, -3)$

$ T(\alpha_{3}) = T(0,0, 1) = (-27, 9, 10)$

$ A(T)_{st}^{st} = \left[ \begin{matrix} -8 & 9 & -27\\ 3 & -2 & 9 \\ 3 & -3 & 10 \end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: Yes, you re right. I did the same.  As I mentioned in my comments above  $T_{B}^{B}$

Comment: This answer is false if OP insists on $T(a,b,c)=(-8x+9y-27z,3x-2y+9z, 3x-3y+10z)$ since then $T(1, 0, 0)$ is not defined. (What is $x, y, z$?)

Comment: $$ A(T)_{st}^{st} = \left[ \begin{matrix} -8 & 3 & 3\\ 9 & -2 & -3 \\ -27 & 9 & 10 \end{matrix} \right]$$ , when $T(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Jan I asked for flag with adm intervention. Somebody else need to evaluate the right answer. It's done. Thank you.